# How do you make an item appear on the next line in android:orientation="horizontal" LinearLayout?

Tags: android

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*I can't add picture yet, but basically I want a Text field which width would be full, and on the next line is a button which is placed in the center.*

I wonder how to make the same thing with android:orientation="horizontal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder how to make the same thing with android:orientation="horizontal".

You don't. If you change the orientation of the layout, it will change fully. If you still want it that way, you will have to use nested Layouts to achieve that effect. Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, in this case the outermost layout is redundant, and you should get rid of it.